# Can anyone tell me why my Blender Python classes are not registering?

Tags: python, operator

I feel this is more of a personal question but I don't understand why Blender is not registering my class as an operation, after I corrected some spelling and syntax errors. My code follows. I only just realized my custom operations needed to be suffixed with brackets () . Once I corrected this then Blender started throwing me errors as it finally registered it needed to do something with the operations, I suppose. I corrected what I can but am unclear on what I'm missing for the classes which are not registering.  It's worth noting I'm coding this in Blender 2.79, for now but may eventually port this over to Blender 2.9. If there are any errors you can anticipate from that porting at a later date I'd appreciate the heads up. Thank You.

```
import bpy
import math

from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C
from mathutils import *
from math import *

from bpy.props import StringProperty

import imp


# This script is designed to encorporate all the basic classes created by/via James Joseph Green of GreenStreamsStudio into a single importable script making the classes callable in other scripts.



class GreenDampedTrackPreCorrection_Nose(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname= "rig.green_prest_damptr_nosecor"
    bl_label = "PreStr_DampNoseCor_Green"
    # Okay I forgot to go through correcting the "Damped Track" Constraints Prior to resetting the "Stretch To" Constraints.
    # To correct this without resetting ALL the code line #s create the Damp Track corrective proceedures in a seperate peice of code to be imported and called by it's classes.
    # These class proceedures MUST be run prior to the "Stretch To"'Resets'.
    # Place Damp Track Corrective Classes' call codes in the "extra code insertion lines" provided (#s 41-46)
    #
    def execute(self, context):
        #
        #Correcting Damped Track proceedures for nose.
        bpy.context.object.pose.bones['DEF-nose'].constraints['Damped Track'].target = bpy.data.objects['rig']
        bpy.context.object.pose.bones['DEF-nose'].constraints['Damped Track'].subtarget = "nose.008"
        # Okay from here on out let it be understood that the main "target" of any of the "Automatically" created constraints which need to be adjusted unless otherwise stated are all already targeted to "rig".
        bpy.context.object.pose.bones['DEF-nose.007'].constraints['Damped Track'].subtarget = "nose.007"
        bpy.context.object.pose.bones['DEF-nose.006'].constraints['Damped Track'].subtarget = 'nose.006'
        bpy.context.object.pose.bones['DEF-nose.005'].constraints['Damped Track'].subtarget = 'nose.001'
        return {'FINISHED'}


class GreenArmatureStretchToReset(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "rig.green_constraint_reset_stretchto"
    bl_label = "ResetStretchGreen"
    #cow = green_constraint_reset_stretchto
    # note: the above line is a new custom convinience variable, added to the dictionary. It will be used extensively to save page space, and to remind us to have fun. :)
    #
    def execute (self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
        c=bpy.context.copy()  # copy the context returns dic.
        # add constraint to the context dictionary
        c["constraint"] = bpy.context.active_pose_bone.constraints['Stretch To']
        # override context by passing dic as first argument
        bpy.ops.constraint.stretchto_reset(c, constraint="Stretch To", owner='BONE')
        return {'FINISHED'}
        # Execute in Pose Mode on desired rig.


class GreenCowConvenienceReset(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "rig.cow"
    bl_label = "ResetStretchGreenDuplicate"
    #cow = green_constraint_reset_stretchto
    # note: this class is a duplicate of the above class GreenArmatureStretchToReset in leu of a working custom convenience variable. It will be used extensively to save page space, and to remind us to have fun. :)
    #
    def execute (self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
        c = bpy.context.copy()
        c["constraint"] = bpy.context.active_pose_bone.constraints['Stretch To']
        bpy.ops.constraint.stretchto_reset(c, constraint="Stretch To", owner='BONE')
        return{'FINISHED'}


class GreenConfirmMode(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "rig.green_confirm_mode"
    bl_label = "ConfirmModeGreen"
    #
    def execute (self, context):
        # Confirming Operating Mode + ProperRig # shunt lines 103 - 109 into a class with call bpy.ops.rig.green_confirm_mode
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['rig']
        bpy.data.objects['rig'].select = True
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
        bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        return {'FINISHED'}


class GreenTakRigMirrorConstraints(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "rig.greentak_constraint_mirror_universal"
    bl_label = "MirrorConstraintsTakGreen"
    #
    def execute (self, context):
        #import bpy
        context = bpy.context
        scene = context.scene
        MyArmature = bpy.data.objects["rig"]
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        MyArmature.select = True
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = MyArmature
        bpy.ops.object.posemode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action='SELECT')
        all_bones = bpy.context.selected_pose_bones
        for bone in all_bones:
            bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            if ".L" in bone.name:
                boneL = MyArmature.data.bones[bone.name]
                boneR = MyArmature.data.bones[bone.name.replace('.L','.R')]
                boneR.select = True
                boneL.select = True
                MyArmature.data.bones.active = boneL
                if len(MyArmature.pose.bones[boneL.name].constraints) !=0:
                    bpy.ops.object.constraints_copy()
                    bpy.ops.pose.constraints_copy()
                    for con in MyArmature.pose.bones[boneR.name].constraints:
                        con.subtarget = con.subtarget.replace('.L','.R')




class CarrieStyleFaceConstraints(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "rig.carrie_style_face_constraint_fix"
    bl_label = "Carrie Face Constraints"
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
    #bpy.ops.rig.green_confirm_mode()# This line is commented out as functions need to be placed AFTER the def[inition] of a class. Otherwise this custom operator causes issues, especially if it's not working.
    #
    def execute (self, context):
        # Execute in PoseMode on desired rig
        # Actual Code Version 1
        ''' Dealing with original bones and subdivided facial only (light purple, red, dark green, and indirectly light green)'''
        # Face
        # Nose
        # Note colours of text will differ in the console.
        bpy.ops.rig.green_confirm_mode# For all intensive purposes please make sure this Operator class GreenConfirmMode has been created prior to running the full script here.
        bpy.data.armatures['rig'].bones.active = bpy.data.armatures['rig'].bones['DEF-nose']
        # Correct Pre-assigned Constraints, Reset Stretch lines
        # In General Concept (Pre Psuado Code)# Page 2 begins.
        # Due to the loose default 'aim to' controler "nose.005"
        # For each new "DEF-nose.0&&" starting @ DEF-nose.005
        # reparent the "DEF-nose." bones the "nose.0&&" bones numbered 1 higher than the given bone,
        # while constraining the given bone to the nose.0&& bone corresponding to it's now .0&& # .
        # Exceptions present in "DEF-nose" to "nose.008" and in "DEF-nose.005" to "nose.001".
        #
        # Changing Modes
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
        # ReParenting
        bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action="DESELECT")
        ## Select the "child to be" first.
        bpy.data.armatures['rig'].bones['DEF-nose.007'].select = True
        bpy.data.armatures['rig'].bones.active = bpy.data.armatures['rig'].bones['nose.008']
        bpy.ops.object.posemode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.armature.parent_set(type='OFFSET')# Page 3 begins.
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.object.posemode_toggle()
        # Continued same task alternate approach #1
        """ Etc. Etc.. The rest of the actual script functions
            are not needed for the sake of troubleshooting.
            It is enough to know that the prior classes
            are used within THIS class.
        """
        return{'FINISHED'}




####

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(GreenDampedTrackPreCorrection_Nose)
    bpy.utils.register_class(GreenArmatureStretchToReset)
    bpy.utils.register_class(GreenCowConvenienceReset)
    bpy.utils.register_class(GreenConfirmMode)
    bpy.utils.register_class(GreenTakRigMirrorConstraints)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GreenDampedTrackPreCorrection_Nose)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GreenArmatureStretchToReset)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GreenCowConvenienceReset)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GreenConfirmMode)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GreenTakRigMirrorConstraints)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(GreenArmatureStretchToReset)
    bpy.utils.register_class(GreenCowConvenienceReset)
    bpy.utils.register_class(CarrieStyleFaceConstraints)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CarrieStyleFaceConstraints)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GreenCowConvenienceReset)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GreenArmatureStretchToReset)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image: These are the classes which Blender "registers" I have, why are the rest missing]

Comment: You realize you define register twice, the second one overwrites the first, and the three classes you see are the three in the second register function?

Comment: @scurest        No, I had not realized that the 2nd register instance (defining register twice) would erase classes it had already defined. I Just thought I could group similar classes together this way. Deliberately defined register the 2nd time so as to achieve this "grouping" thought the 2nd register defining would only effect classes already in the 1st definition. Thank You for your comment, as I had not realized the consequences of "sequences", I have now corrected the issue as per your comment and the code works fine now. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept your answer.

Comment: Here is what the corrected code looks like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0i04tg6wty2ca9/Scripted%20Proceedures%20Carried-Out.txt?dl=0     And here is the results confirmed to work in Blender:      https://www.dropbox.com/s/oc6pfbuxru079o5/ClassRegistryIssuesRepaired_JJGreen_scurest.PNG?dl=0     Again Thanks.